# Why do we use server-side templating engines for Node?

Tags: node.js, templates, server-side, templating, templating-engine

For example I see Node.js a lot of peopple have been mentioning using jade or swig. I am building a Node.js app that will use RESTful interface for communicating with the client. I want to be able to send and receive updates. A lot of tutorials I've been seeing or apps I have been seeing online use jade or some other template engine.

What is the advantage of using a templating engine on the server vs. just serving up a bunch of regular html/javascript and allowing the client to render certain pages based on what information is sent to it from the server? How does a server-side tmeplating engine improve a use of a RESTful interface? edit: is there any advantage or is it just personal preference?

If it is advantageous in some way, I will invest the time to learn it now before I get too far in my project rather than wish I had learned it earlier :-D

[Here](http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/building-a-login-system-in-node-js-and-mongodb/) is an example that uses Jade-lang.

Comment: Templating and RESTfulness are orthogonal.

Comment: As in, they have nothing to do with each other. Okay that's good to know

Answer (score 0):

SGML-like markup languages are hard for both computers and programmers to read. Template engines usually help speed up programming by using smaller tokens and syntax. Also, if you go through a pre-processor that templating requires, you can add variables and logic usually.

The downside is that it takes cycles to render the template. Usually though this isn't a problem, as most projects are hindered by time-to-market and not lack of processing efficiency.

I use [Jade](https://github.com/dscape/jade) for most of my projects, because it's very easy to transition from HTML to Jade and also intuitive. I had hardly any learning curve difficulties going from HTML to Jade.

Answer (score 0):

An advantage to templating engines is as they are running server side you can do permission checks directly within the template. You could even send all of the user's data inside of the template all in one request.

They have their upsides and downsides, but security is a big upside as you're not relying on the client to ignore the data its not supposed to see.

There are other ways to do this but this is for sure one of the easiest as it's all done in a single request.

I also want to note real quick that they are not replacements for other forms of permission checks, you need those too. They just help in not putting too much trust into the client.